# Knuth long division algorithm

Tags: algorithm, integer-division, arbitrary-precision

I'm implementing algorithm D of section 4.3.2 of volume 2 of *The Art of Computer Programming* by D. E. Knuth.

On step D3 I'm supposed to compute `q = floor(u[j+n]*BASE+u[j+n-1] / v[n-1])` and `r = u[j+n]*BASE+u[j+n-1] mod v[n-1]`. Here, `u` (dividend) and `v` (divisor) are single-precision* arrays of length `m+n` and `n`, respectively. `BASE` is the representation base, which for a binary computer of 32 or 64 bits equals to 2^32 or 2^64, respectively.

My question is about the precision in which `q` and `r` are represented. As I understand the rest of the algorithm, they are supposed to be single-precision*, but its easy to spot many cases where they must be double-precision* to fit the result.

How are those values supposed to be computed? In what precision?

`*` The expression single/double-precision refers to integer arithmetic, not to floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When divisor is normalized (most significant bit set), quotient always will fit in a single word. With a power of two base representation, normalization is accomplished by cheap left shift operations.

[Link to a more detailed and formal answer.](https://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf)